# Excel - paste multiple rows after every row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with order data where each row is a different order.  Each order has multiple items, all on the same row.  I'm trying to move each additional item into a new row beneath the original.  I created the cell calls for the first row, but I'm wondering how to go about copy/pasting (inserting) those additional rows beneath each row containing the orders.

In effect, the columns are like this:

```
[order number] [customer info] [item info] [item info] [item info] [item info]
```

And I need it to be

```
[order number] [customer info] [item info]
                               [item info]
                               [item info]
                               [item info]
```

Is there a means to copy that 2nd, 3rd & 4th row of cell calls and insert/paste them below each row?  Effectively pasting multiple rows after every row?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of column unwrapping is easy enough if each row has the same amount of additional items or at least the same maximum number of additional items.

Say you have max 5 items per row. In a new sheet, you can use INDEX to unwrap the data in column C (items):

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$Z, INT((ROW()-1)/5)+1, MOD((ROW()-1),5)+3)
```

So

```
Row 1 would index to sheet1!R1C3 i.e. order 1 item 1
Row 2 would index to sheet1!R1C4 i.e. order 1 item 2
...
Row 5 would index to sheet1!R1C7 i.e. order 1 item 5
Row 6 would index to sheet1!R2C3 i.e. order 2 item 1
Row 7 would index to sheet1!R2C4 i.e. order 2 item 2
Etc.
```

You use the same logic to list the order number and customer name only for every 5th row i.e. `IF(MOD(ROW()-1,5)=0, INDEX(...), "")`.

Now obviously for rows that have less than the maximum number of items you will generate blank rows, of more precisely return rows with zero values. You can use an auto-filter to filter all values not equal to zero. However, an auto-filter will require a header row, meaning your first data row will not be row 1 as per the example above but rather row 2. To correct for this, you just need to adjust the ROW offset to ROW()-2 in the formula above. Similarly if you have a header in the original data, offset the row INDEX with another +1, i.e. INT((ROW()-1)/5)+2.

Comment: If you really dont want the blank/zero rows, or impose the x item limit, you could add helper columns that track the current INDEX row and column numbers, say in columns A and B respectively. Starting with A1 = 1 and B1 = 3, the next row's "row index" in A2 might be something like `=IF(ISBLANK(INDEX(SHEET1!$A:$Z, A1, B1)), A1+1, A1)` and the column index in B2 like `=IF(ISBLANK(INDEX(SHEET1!$A:$Z, A1, B1)), 3, B1+1)`

Comment: Sorry, I think my description was possibly confusing, so I'll elaborate:

I have 5500 rows of orders, with columns A-IS.  The first item is inexplicably listed in a much earlier column, with the rest added at the end (if they exist).  I created a sheet that calls each additional cell in place below the first listed item.  What I'm trying to avoid is clicking "insert copied cells" 5500 times and just paste these cells between every order line.  I've created dummy data here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b3af0wovesup0yd/DummyData.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Indeed what I have described is an automated way to achieve what you are trying to do using formulae. No need to copy paste thousands of times. The formulae in the new sheet automatically leaves a number of blank rows (5 - 1 = 4 rows in my example) between rows and populate them with the additional items. You only copy the formula down and across the new sheet **once**, and it will auto populate all the data. I suggest you try this on a simple data set first, with all the items in order in columns C to G. When you understand how it works, try and adjust it for the real data

Comment: Ps. I had a look at your demo spreadsheet. The difference is my formula references the original data in sheet1 (your FullData sheet). You don't have to insert new between rows, as say every 5'th row refers back to row (row#/5) in FullData.  E.g. try this `=IF(MOD(ROW()-1,5)=0, INDEX(FullData!$A:$ZZ, INT((ROW()-1)/5)+1, COLUMN()), "")` to "clone" a sheet with 4 blank rows between every original data row. You can of course  add as many blanks you need.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it: I put in the largest number of rows I want to split by, paste my cell calls below, and then that repeat that whole section as many times as I need - yeah?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well yes exactly, and if you add my first formula to column C it will pull down/transpose the values in D E F and G etc automatically so you wont need your cell calls and duplication of data at all. You just need to modify my fomula to get grab values from not columns 3 but whichever column in your data item 2 starts.

Comment: Worked like a dream, thank you so much!!!

Comment: Awesome. Kindly checkmark the answer so others may know your question has been solved.